# Failed to import WordCloud from wordcloud

Tags: python, anaconda, word-cloud

I installed wordcloud package for my 64 bit windows 10 system with anaconda python 3.5
  using `python -m pip install D:\folder\wordcloud-1.5.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` 
                                                                            command.
  It has been successfully installed.
  But when I am trying to import `from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS`, I am getting error.Please check this:

[image]

Has it something to do with the path of **wordcloud-1.5.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl** file as I have placed it in some random folder?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you do not import STOPWORDS, just WordCloud?

Comment: Getting the same error : ImportError: cannot import name 'WordCloud'

Comment: If you named the file wordcloud.py that can also cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to trace the error is to import the package (which apparently works) with `import wordcloud` and then list all members of the package with `help(wordcloud)`. Check if the version and functions match your expectations. Check if it also matches the documentation of your package.

I suspect that the name of the `WordCloud`class was simply changed.

If you miss functions then your package is broken. If the version number is wrong then you downloaded an old package. Use the Anaconda Navigator that usually comes with Anaconda to reinstall the package. If you do not have the Navigator use whatever package manager you have.

Comment: I also think the package is broken as I am not getting any functions under help(wordcloud). By the way thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you can't see any functions than it is probably broken.

Comment: If the .py file is named wordcloud.py it will also return this error.